# Parameter Pass a TCPClient Object

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I have a Method to handle client data. I currently have this:

```cs
private void HandleClientData(TcpClient c)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
            string data = null;

            TcpClient client = c;
            c.Close();

            client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;

        }
```

Now, does the line: `TcpClient client = c;` cause a loss of the client, even if a new `TcpClient` is created using `c`.

I have read somewhere that all references all share an underlying `socket`, however, would reinitialising it like this allow the user to still send data through or would the line: `c.Close();` completely end the connection?

*Please note: I do not currently have code to test this myself, as it has not been written yet, this question will also help me to understand more `TcpClient` handling in further projects. Thanks.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TcpClient client = c;
```

This line doesn't create a copy of `c`, it is a new reference to the very same thing `c` is.  There is still only 1 TcpClient instance.

Therefore, when you do:

```
c.Close();
```

It closes the reference to `c` (and therefore `client` is also closed as they are the same thing).

They don't just share the same 'socket', they are exactly the same thing with 2 different variable names.

Comment: Do you know a way to get around this? Also ty for the response.
Again, the reason I mentioned the socket, is because of something I read prior to this.

Comment: Why do you want to 'get around this'.  This is how the language and the network works.  What have you read that makes you think like this?

Comment: I realise... The problem is how would I then handle multiple connections... Would I have to only be able to do it async until the data is handled?

Comment: If your program is the server, every time a connection is made from a client, you get a new TcpClient instance.  This is a representation of the socket and will live in memory until the connection is closed.

Comment: [TcpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8) is what I used to get a grasp of TCP Stuff. From the code example it looks like that any inbound connections would wait for the rest of the code to execute. Is this what you're refering to?

Comment: You have 1 TcpListener that waits for a connection, and each time AcceptTcpClient returns a new connection (TcpClient), you kick off a new thread/task to handle that connection and AcceptTcpClient goes back to waiting for another connection.  The example you linked to doesn't kick of a new thread for each connection, which is possibly why you are confused

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Thanks.